Are there theorems about existence of positive invariant set in dynamical systems?
I have next task: $\dot x=f(x),$ where $x=0$ is global asymptotic stable point. I want to prove inverted Lyapunov theorem about existing Lyapunov function. And for a fully geometric proof I need the existence of positive invariant set for such a system. I’ve read Khalil about it and didn't get into how to construct such set by $\beta(r,s)\in \mathcal{KL}.$

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

What is $\mathcal{KL}.$ ? Besides, please, give complete references for the book by Khalil.

Inversed Lyapunov theorem is Theorem 4.17. For my case we should use lemma 3.3. instead of first part of proof in Khalil.

\textbf{Definition 3.3} A continuous function $ \alpha : [0, a) \rightarrow [0, \infty) $ is said to belong to class $ \mathcal{K} $ if it is strictly increasing and $ \alpha(0) = 0 $. It is said to belong to class $ \mathcal{K}_\infty $ if $ a = \infty $ and $ \alpha(r) \rightarrow \infty $ as $ r \rightarrow \infty $.

\textbf{Definition 3.4} A continuous function $ \beta : [0, a) \times [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty) $ is said to belong to class $ \mathcal{KL} $ if, for each fixed $ s $, the mapping $ \beta(r, s) $ belongs to class $ \mathcal{K} $ with respect to $ r $, and for each fixed $ r $, the mapping $ \beta(r, s) $ is decreasing with respect to $ s $ and $ \beta(r, s) \rightarrow 0 $ as $ s \rightarrow \infty $.
